# What does "dullness" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I understand that we strive for safety, prosperity, comfort, and long life. But what does it mean to strive for dullness?

> We all strive for safety, prosperity, comfort, long life, and **dullness**.

Context: [*Thinking Like a Mountain* By Aldo Leopold](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: Dull, as in a _prosaic_ life.

Comment: Dullness: lack of excitement. As in, most of us want a sheltered life. However exciting I think Jack Bauer's life must be, I wouldn't trade 24 hours with him.

Comment: So, it means being comfort?

Comment: No, it means _safe_.

Answer (score 1):

[Dullness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dullness), as described by the Free Dictionary, has several senses. The primary sense has the synonym "boring." There is a second sense which means "stupid" but in the context cited, "boring" and not "stupid" is the intended sense of the word.

Dullness is not a word with a connotation as positive as "comfort", instead it is merely a lack of excitement.

The sense of the entire phrase is akin to the [allegedly Chinese curse](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/12/18/live/): "May you live in interesting times."